# update nls_database_parameters Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso alterar os parâmetros `nls` do Oracle, colocando as características da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já testei uma série de dicas, mas sempre diz que tenho privilégios insuficientes.

Essas são as minhas configurações:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a resposta está em seu comentário. Se o erro é relacionado a privilégios insuficientes, seu usuário não possui autorização para alterar os parâmetros. Independente do método utilizado, o servidor do Banco de Dados irá barrar a alteração.